# The account "" has no team with ID "", coincides with new iOS dev license?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

In submitting approximately our hundredth app update, we've run into a very strange coincidence (I think!) which I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.

On October 2nd, we opted to renew our dev license (which expired Oct 10th or so - 1 week early is fine right?). We then submitted a big release, 1.1, without any issues, around October 5th.

I've been working with XCode building/testing locally just fine for the past 2 weeks.

Then things went to hell when I tried to Upload an archive to the app store. I got the title error message "The account `my name` has no team with ID `my-team's-production-app-id-prefix`". This **scared me.**

I would be worried someone kicked me off the team, because that's what it seemed like the error was stating. Except I am the team's agent (confirmed this many times).

I then logged onto dev.apple member center and noticed all my Device IDs needed to be "transferred over" in a renewal step, likely due to the renewal, except I thought this would have been required for the last build?

When I go to Preferences->Account(select my account)->ViewDetails, I get this same error again. I also noticed that after logging in with my Apple ID, it says "Free Free" next to my name, and Agent Agent next to my organization, but I do not remember there being both an organization and name (row) in this interface. I just remember seeing agent twice.

I've tried adjusting all my build settings to use the organization, I've tried logging into admin accounts (Rather than the agent) to test the organization (Error Fetching Developer Info, consistently), I've tried setting the General->Team ID differently but there's only my organization (don't think anything is amiss here), I've tried redownloading all of the correct certificates, I've tried cleaning the application, and basically repeated many of these steps in different orders combined with XCode restarts, unsuccessfully.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it sounds like you have done all of the logical steps but since I did not see it explicitly listed in your question...

When I received the same error this morning after updating to Xcode 7.1.1, it told me that I had to create an App Specific Password out of the blue (probably because I have 2 step verification turned on).

I created one, entered it into the password field and then received the same error as you. So I removed my account completely from Xcode and re-added it (just hit the minus (-) sign and then the plus (+) sign). That seemed to fix the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Find your history BundleIdentifiers, then copy one to your new Product Bundle Identifier.

[image: XCode snapshot]